# Why does my C++ program silently exit when a use a NULL object?

Tags: c++

```
string n = NULL;

cout << "blah: " << n << " foo!" << endl; // never printed

cout << "BLAH" << endl; // never printed

cerr << "FOO" << endl; // never printed
```

I understand assigning or appending something to NULL is not right. But silently dying is not good either. How should I handle / debug those situations? And why is the program dying?

Comment: As you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) , initializing a string with a null ptr leads to _undefined behaviour_

Comment: A `std::string` object, when default constructed (as in `std::string n;`) is empty. If you want an empty string, all you have to do is create the object, no special or explicit initialization needs to be done.

Comment: @NathanOliver The problem isn't that NULL is a pointer. It is that it is the null pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza But `NULL` should only be used with pointers.  `n` is not a pointer so you should never have `n = NULL`

Comment: You should see a [core dump](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f9d8b7f07c77ebe) or similar.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::string` can be initialized with a pointer. C++ allows converting constructors.

Comment: [...but not NULL](http://ideone.com/zouHmB).

Comment: @NathanOliver `NULL` isn't in the standard in the first place. And juanchopanza is right, it's the value that's problematic, not the type.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah yes.  I forgot about that.  `NULL` is the issue but not for the reason I originally though.

Comment: So many discussion and questions about this but 4 down votes. Weird!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - `NULL` most certainly is in the C++ standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker Where?

Comment: @JacobsWright the question is being downvoted because it's exhibiting UB. There are multiple ways to reduce undefined behaviour in your code, and not using things like `NULL` is one of them. In general, it can be avoided with basic, proper programming practices idiomatic to C++ which this code lacks, hence the downvotes.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - [support.types]/3.

Comment: @PeteBecker Alright, I stand corrected. Ghosts from the (C) past still reign strong, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is free to do whatever the implementation of `std::string` you have choses to. `std::string` has a constructor taking a `const char* s`.  However, this involves:

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by `s`. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if `s` does not point at an array of at least `Traits::length(s)+1` elements of `CharT`, **including the case when s is a null pointer.**
>
> (emphasis mine)

<sub>Via [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)</sub>

Comment: Is this correct even though NULL has no type associated with it (except perhaps `void *`)?  I would believe that NULL would be convert to character and then the character assigned to the string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `void *` of `NULL` picks the `const CharT*` overload.

Answer (score 0):

You should just leave `n` uninitialized instead, assigning it to NULL in C++11 can lead to undefined behavior. There should not be an instance in which you need to assign to NULL.

Comment: `n` wouldn't be unitialized, because it's a class type. Its constructor will properly initialize it to an empty string.